# How to install a Virgo FTP on ubuntu 12.10 on Session fallback desktop

Tags: installation, 12.10, install-from-source, zip

I am using **Ubuntu 12.10** with **session fallback desktop** and really very much confused about how to install a software on Ubuntu. Please clarify few issue. I want to install **virgoFTP** . I download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/qftp/ . it is .zip file . I extract it on /Download folder as it is.. but there no clear information how to use this? here is Running section from **readme.txt** file of virgoftp folder

```
RUNNING:
1. Extract this .zip file.
2. Change to the 'virgoftp' directory where the files were extracted.
3. Change the script be executable using "chmod u+x virgoftp"
3. Start virgoftp by running the script named 'virgoftp' using "./virgoftp"
```

So please tell me

- In which folder I have to paste its respective folders . in  **/user/lib** or **/opt** or **/var/lib/**.
- How to make an desktop shortcut for Virgo FTP?
- How to run VirgoFTP?

Answer (score 1):

- The location directory depends on personal preference. I'd use /opt, but any of those you mentioned, or the home folder would do.
- Assuming it's in /opt, create a text file with the following content

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Virgo FTP
  Comment=Virgo FTP
  Exec=/opt/virgoftp/virgoftp
  Icon=/opt/virgoftp/image/virgoftp32.png
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=System;Settings;GNOME;GTK;
  StartupNotify=true
  ```
- Again, assuming it's been put in /opt, open a terminal window and run

  ```
  bash /opt/virgoftp/virgoftp
  ```

Comment: where I have to save this text file and with which name?

Comment: I write it and save as `virgo.txt` on desktop and run `bash...` command you provided. it gives **java: command not found** error

Comment: Save it in the home folder, and a good name is probably `virgoftp`, but it's up to you. The default location for these launchers is /usr/share/applications, so, if you want it available globally (for all users), move it there.

Comment: Looks like it needs java, so search for it in the software center and install.

Comment: My Location directory is **/usr/lib** and I write above content replacing `/opt` with `/usr/lib` in a file name **virgoftp** on **/usr/share**

Comment: Whatever you prefer, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help . I m currently installing  `OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime` from ubuntu software center. is this a right package?

Comment: I am not quite sure it is the right package. JDK stands for Java Developement Kit, while you probably need the VM. Try searching for `icedtea`, there are `icedtea-6-jre-jamvm` and `icedtea-7-jre-jamvm`, and you might need the older one, because the latest release of virgoftp is from 2009.

Comment: On the second though, and after looking through the packages, openjdk-7-jre or openjdk-6-jre is probably what's needed.